# Trigger function at specific window size

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div that follows the browser as it scrolls and is contained within another div.

The following function keeps my div in place and moving when the user scrolls:

```
        $(function() {
            var offset = $("#sidebar").offset();
            var topPadding = 15;
            $(window).scroll(function() {
                if ($(window).scrollTop() > offset.top) {
                    $("#sidebar").stop().animate({
                        marginTop: $(window).scrollTop() - offset.top + topPadding
                    });
                } else {
                    $("#sidebar").stop().animate({
                        marginTop: 0
                    });
                };
            });
        });
```

This works pretty well, except when the browser height is less than 400px, then it gets buggy.

So I thought I'd include a simple line to get it to only run when the browser is >=400 as such:

```
 if (window.innerHeight >= 400) {
        $(function() {
            var offset = $("#sidebar").offset();
            var topPadding = 15;
            $(window).scroll(function() {
                if ($(window).scrollTop() > offset.top) {
                    $("#sidebar").stop().animate({
                        marginTop: $(window).scrollTop() - offset.top + topPadding
                    });
                } else {
                    $("#sidebar").stop().animate({
                        marginTop: 0
                    });
                };
            });
        });
        }
```

This seems to work fine so long as the initial browser height is greater than 400px.  If the browser window is resized from it's initial height, the code will still execute, which is counter to what I want.

Essentially, is there a way to dynamically track the browser size and only run this code when the height is larger than 400px and not run when less than 400px?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: *"I have a div that follows the browser as it scrolls:"* Can I just say: As a user, I ***hate*** those. ;-)

Comment: Haha, me too when used for nefarious purposes. But this is a functional div that presents information on user selected variables on the page. So it lets the user keep track of their selections as they scroll down, which is pretty useful, it seems.

Comment: @ rdrkra: I usually don't like them even then. Instead, making preferences lists shorter, multi-step, or in their own scrolling region would be my approach.

Comment: Yeah, been thinking of moving to a multi-step approach which would present preference list of radio buttons in blocks. We'll see if I can get this to work and what sort of UX feedback I get...otherwise probably will go that route, as you suggest.

Answer (score 1):

Just move the check *into* your event handler:

```
$(function() {
    var offset = $("#sidebar").offset();
    var topPadding = 15;
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if (window.innerHeight >= 400) {  // <=== Moved it here
            if ($(window).scrollTop() > offset.top) {
                $("#sidebar").stop().animate({
                    marginTop: $(window).scrollTop() - offset.top + topPadding
                });
            } else {
                $("#sidebar").stop().animate({
                    marginTop: 0
                });
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Now the check is done when you're processing the `scroll` event, rather than just once at the outset preventing the scroll from being hooked at all.

---

Separately, because you're doing this on the `scroll` event, which happens pretty often, I'd try to minimize the number of times you wrap or look up elements. Instead of doing it on every event, since `window` isn't going to change and I suspect your `sidebar` isn't going to change either, wrap/look them up *once*:

```
$(function() {
    var offset = $("#sidebar").offset();
    var topPadding = 15;
    var sideBar = $("#sidebar"); 
    var $window = $(window);
    $window.scroll(function() {
        if ($window.height() >= 400) {  // <=== Moved it here
            if ($window.scrollTop() > offset.top) {
                sidebar.stop().animate({
                    marginTop: $window.scrollTop() - offset.top + topPadding
                });
            } else {
                sidebar.stop().animate({
                    marginTop: 0
                });
            }
        }
    });
});
```

That also makes it reasonable to use jQuery's `height` function on `window` for cross-browser compatibility.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Tried the code out but it doesn't seem to work out. Div doesn't follow the scroll anymore across all browsers. The reason why I thought monitoring the events dynamically was because if the user resized the window during a session to less than 400, I woudln't want the div to follow the scroll at all, just sit at it's default position.

Comment: @rdrkra: It should follow them until/unless window height is < 400, at which point it won't move at all (you might want to add an `else` and put it in a specific position).

Comment: @TJ _"you might want to add an else and put it in a specific position"_ are you referring to the else statement or the actual script being put in a specific position? (i.e. just before the div in question). Sorry, my greenhorns might be showing a bit...

Comment: @rdrkra: An `else` for the case where the window height is less than 400. Just set the div to a specific location.

Comment: @TJ Ahh I see what you mean. Ok let me play around a bit and see if I can get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

To track the browser width & height as it is being resized:

```
$(window).resize(function()
{
    var viewportWidth = $(window).width();
    var viewportHeight = $(window).height();

    // More code here...
};
```

However, I think there is a better way to keep your div in place, one that does not involve Javascript. Have you tried using `position:fixed`?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Yeah, I've tried `position:fixed` but it doesn't keep the div constrained to the height of another div. At least not easily. JS seems to be the easiest way to get this sort of functionality, or so I've read. How would I call the `viewportHeight` var into my above code? Tried a few different ways but couldn't get it to work out...